# counter occurences to obtain a weight per user. (pyspark)

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, merge

I am new to Spark.
I am trying to make a recommendation system, in order to obtain implicit weights i wanted to count how many time a user has ordered a product. I am strugeling with this.

i have a table with user_id, product_id and weight. these id's are not unique, i would like to count how many times a user_id has ordered a product_id.

for example

from:

USER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, WEIGHT

5, 196, 1

5, 196, 1

99623, 196, 1

99623, 196, 1

99623, 196, 1

99623, 200, 1

to:

USER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, WEIGHT

5 , 196, 2

99623, 196, 3

99623, 200, 1

(i am using pyspark)

here is a screenshot of my dataframe
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFysP.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Rather than screenshots, plese consider pasting your actual code in the question. It will show your effort and what you have tried. And it will make finding the problem easier. Try to aim for a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by and sum:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('USER_ID', 'PRODUCT_ID').agg(F.sum('WEIGHT').alias('WEIGHT'))
```

Or use `F.count` instead of `F.sum` if you just want to count the items.